# Instructions to install a KDE4 application on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, cygwin, kde-4

This question was off-topic on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/499140/instructions-to-install-a-kde4-application-on-windows?) so I decided to post it here. I am using Windows 8.1 and I don't use Linux so I have never installed something like Cygwin even though I heard about it many times. I want to install a program called "Cirkuit". It is a KDE4 GUI-app that creates circuit diagrams and converts them into Latex code. Here is the [official website of the program](https://wwwu.uni-klu.ac.at/magostin/cirkuit.html).

How to install all the required stuff to make it up and running on a Windows PC so that I can get back to writing Latex documents.

Comment: I don't think Cygwin will be enough.  KDE requires a lot of infrastructure.  KDE has an ongoing project to port their software to Windows, but I don't know what the status is.  This would be a good place to start: https://community.kde.org/Windows.  If your computer has the resources, you could install Linux with KDE in a VM, or just install it dual boot or as a portable USB-based linux system.

Comment: @fixer1234 I really thought like I want to avoid to install a VM because it makes no sense to install a VM just because of one single program I intend to use. But according to your explanation, this is the safest option, right?

Comment: I would check out that link first.  It might be possible to do it in Windows.  If not, and if you don't need to run it concurrent with Windows and it's just the one program, I'd be tempted to stick a bare-bones Linux KDE distro on a flash drive and run it from there.

Comment: There is no rush. I'd be very grateful of your help to install Cirkuit since I am beginner in this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've been away from Windows for some years (I now use Win 7 just to print coupons for my wife because that only works in Windows).  I've never tried installing Linux stuff in Windows so I can't be much help on this one.  Maybe a good spot to check on this would be KDE's forum.  They will have the highest concentration of subject matter experts: https://forum.kde.org/.

Comment: Thank you for the forum link. I'm giving it a try right away.

Comment: You can use Linux subsystem in Windows aka. LXSS aka. WSL.

Comment: @Biswapriyo, do you know if you can install KDE/Plasma in WSL?

Comment: @Biswapriyo, thanks for the info.  Looks like an avenue to pursue.  KDE requires Qt, which the mentioned DEs don't use, and it appears some tweaking may be required.  The OP is on Win 8.1, but I understand people can still upgrade to Win 10 free.

Comment: Bummer.  As of 5 mos ago, "WSL does not aim to support GUI desktops or applications (e.g. Gnome, KDE, etc.)".  More info: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq.  It sounds like Microsoft doesn't "aim to support " it, but people have had some level of success making it do it for some DEs.

Comment: I have succeeded to run KDE programs on windows with `kdewin`: https://download.kde.org/stable/kdewin/installer/

Comment: @mpy is there a possibility to run Cirkuit then? Using your method?

Comment: Hm, I just checked... I use an outdated version, where Cirkuit is not in their repositories. Maybe it is now available out of the box, but I'm not sure, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

In general it is possible to compile a program from source in cygwin if it runs in Linux.

The method is the same as reported on https://wwwu.uni-klu.ac.at/magostin/cirkuit.html
without the sudo portion that in cygwin does not exist:

```
tar xzvf cirkuit-x.y.z.tar.gz
cd cirkuit-x.y.z
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=`kde4-config --prefix`
make
make install
```

of course you will need to install all needed tools
https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-net.html#setup-packages

You will need as minimum the compiler `gcc-core` plus `cmake` and `make`
plus the package that contains `kde4-config`.

```
 $ cygcheck -p bin/kde4-config
Found 6 matches for bin/kde4-config
...
libkdecore5-4.14.38-3 - libkdecore5: KDE4 application framework
```

The suggested packages for Debian

> texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-recommended texlive-pstricks
>   texlive-base-bin texlive-extra-utils preview-latex-style m4
>   ghostscript pdf2svg cmake kdelibs5-dev libqt4-dev libpoppler-qt4-dev

have equal or similar names in Cygwin. As example:

> libpoppler-qt4-dev ->  libpoppler-qt4-devel

the full list of available packages:
https://cygwin.com/packages/package_list.html

Comment: @Whoa. I can't thank you enough for this. This is my first program installation using cygwin so please can you be more explicit just for this time? I mean I don't know for example how I should download the required packages in the first place.

Comment: I didn't understand the `cygcheck -p bin/kde4-config` command. What information does this give? And @matzeri please can you list up the suggested Debian package names in Cygwin. I cannot find some of them and it is confusing for me.

Comment: It provides the name of packages that contain `bin/kde4-config` . So a command `kde4-config` in a `bin` directory

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance as I am no Linux user. I just needed Cikuit to run on my Windows PC and now I am stuck.